# biblatex-examples.bib is incorrectly being used as a bibliography source

Tags: biblatex, texlipse

I have just made the transition to [Biblatex](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) and [Biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) and something strange is happening.

I load the `biblatex` package and it's working normally:

```
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt,
style=apa,
natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Then I add the `bib` file:

`\addbibresource{./biblist.bib}`

However, when I compile, I get warnings that an article/bookt etc.. is missing a required field. Here's an example:

`article aksin is missing required field year`

There are many more of them and all of them are not in my bibliography file. They are actually in a file called `biblatex-examples.bib` which is stored in:

`/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib`

The file can be obtained from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) as well.

These errors **do not** appear in the log file but only in Eclipse (TeXlipse). Also, the items in that file do not appear in the compiled pdf file! I want to know why is this file being used and how can I stop that. I've got enough warnings to deal with!

---

**Edit:**
1- The warnings do not disappear after loading the file using `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`. In fact, the `bib` file isn't compiled or included at all.

2- This is strange, there is nothing about `biber` in the log file. However, everything about the bibliography is in the `.blg` file. Here is what's in that file:

```
[1] Config.pm:300> INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
[1] Config.pm:303> INFO - Logfile is 'phdthesis.blg'
[2] biber:145> INFO - === Mon Jun 25, 2012, 21:09:08
[3] Biber.pm:271> INFO - Reading 'phdthesis.bcf'
[38] Biber.pm:586> INFO - Found 52 citekeys in bib section 0
[56] Biber.pm:2585> INFO - Processing bib section 0
[94] Biber.pm:2677> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file './biblist.bib' for section 0
[101] bibtex.pm:833> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[131] bibtex.pm:837> INFO - Finished Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[132] bibtex.pm:708> INFO - Found BibTeX data source './biblist.bib'
[478] Biber.pm:2480> INFO - Sorting list 'MAIN' keys
[479] Biber.pm:2484> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_GB.UTF-8'
[746] Biber.pm:2480> INFO - Sorting list 'SHORTHANDS' keys
[747] Biber.pm:2484> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_GB.UTF-8'
[869] bbl.pm:427> INFO - Writing 'phdthesis.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[882] bbl.pm:498> INFO - Output to phdthesis.bbl
```

3- I deleted all the `aux` files and tried again. The warnings still appear.

I have a feeling it's a TeXlipse issue, I went and checked for the arguments passed when compiling documents, there was nothing other than `%input` for bother Biber and BibTex.

Just in case a package related to Biblatex is causing this issue. This is what I load:

```
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt,
style=apa,
natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

Comment: Do the warnings disappear if you add `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` in the line right after your own bibliography?

Comment: what does your log file say? there should be a message what files are loaded.

Comment: Did you ever use that examples file? Maybe deleting all your aux files could help.

Comment: I have the suspect that TeXlipse is reading a file in another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Although the file `biblatex-examples.bib` is located in:

`/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib`

I found it in TeXlipse project explorer. I don't know how it turned up there. I removed it *only* from the project explorer and the warnings disappeared.

**Maybe** the first time biblatex/biber are used, this file is imported automatically in the project. I'll be installing TeXlive on another computer and I'll try it.